# should I use singular or plural verb

Tags: grammar

It's a sentence from my dictionary:

> Years of smoking ***have*** taken their toll on his health.

I'm wondering why it uses "have" instead of "has". I know "years" is in the plural, but "years of smoking" is just a single thing at large. The point is on "smoke", not "years". I can just simplify the subject as "smoking" if I want. But it would be wrong if I simplify the subject as "years" and omit "smoking" because time is not the reason, smoking is. So in this case, I feel the following sentence is right:

> Years of smoking ***has*** taken their toll on his health.

But the right verb should be in the plural, why? How to explain this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mechanically, *years* is the plural subject, and requires a verb in plural concord:

> Years ... **have** taken ...

However, you may also with perfect propriety treat *Years of smoking* as a ‘single thing at large’, and use the singular verb in concord:

> Years of smoking **has taken** ...

But if you do so, you must do so consistently, throughout the sentence; a singular subject cannot act as referent for plural pronoun<sup>†</sup>:

> Years of smoking **has** taken **its** toll on his health.

---

<sup>†</sup> except in the special case of the degenderative *they*.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is a very abstract idea. Grammatically both of them are correct. But each case gives *slightly* different feeling to the reader.
If you are generally talking about a large amount of time spent smoking as `years of smoking`, and you want to say something about that time then `has` makes more sense. But if you are talking about specifically `years` which were passed smoking then `have` makes more sense.